# Print text file in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I am trying to load a text file from server in a html page, and print the content. The text file has specific format, so I can not change it.
Below is my sample code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Print test</title>
    <script>
        var url = './text.txt';
        function load() {
            fetch(url).then(function(resp) {
                resp.text().then(function(text) {
                    var id = document.getElementById("abc");
                    id.textContent = text;
                });
            });
        }
        function print() {
            var id = document.getElementById("abc");
            var printwindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
            printwindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            printwindow.document.write(id.textContent);
            printwindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printwindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            printwindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            printwindow.print();
            printwindow.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <pre id="abc" style="height:85%;overflow:auto; background:white">
    </pre>
    <button onclick="load()">Load</button>
    <button onclick="print()">Print</button>
</body>
```

A sample text file is following :

text.txt

```
NAME                    = ABC
SURNAME                 = CDE
OCCUPATION              = XYZ
PLACE                   = UUU
```

When I click the load button, the text is loaded as it is, but when I try to print in, it is garbled, as shown in the following picture:
[image]

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: The content is INSIDE the <pre> tag

Comment: I added Below it worked for me

Comment: function print() {
            var id = document.getElementById("abc");
            var printwindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
            printwindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            printwindow.document.write("<pre>" + id.textContent + "</pre>");
            printwindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printwindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            printwindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            printwindow.print();
            printwindow.close();
        }

Comment: Modify your function print()  as I did Below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Print test</title>
    <script>
        var url = './text.txt';
        function load() {
            fetch(url).then(function (resp) {
                resp.text().then(function (text) {
                    var id = document.getElementById("abc");
                    id.textContent = text;
                });
            });
        }
        function print() {
            var id = document.getElementById("abc");
            var printwindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');
            printwindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            printwindow.document.write("<pre>" + id.textContent + "</pre>");
            printwindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printwindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            printwindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            printwindow.print();
            printwindow.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <pre id="abc" style="height:85%;overflow:auto; background:white">
    </pre>
    <button onclick="load()">Load</button>
    <button onclick="print()">Print</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are losing the formatted text because when you open the pop-up, you are appending the text without"pre" tag, which keep the formatted aspect.

You just need to append "pre" tag in the pop-up :

```
printwindow.document.write('</head><body ><pre>');
printwindow.document.write(id.textContent);
printwindow.document.write('</pre></body></html>');
```